# Object from Observable<T> with subscribe() does not print values

Tags: java, observable, rx-java2

I've been trying to understand rxJava Observable for more than a day now, but I just can't figure out what I need for my case. I think because I am not creating an Observable, but merely getting one returned from an API call and I need the class of the type of Observable it is so I can use the object properties of the class.

Here is my code, but when I run the print statements gets skipped entirely. How can I use object properties wrapped in an Observer?

```
// Define woman friend by creating their own large person group person.
// Returns an Observable<Person>.
rx.Observable<Person> personW = client.largePersonGroupPersons()
    .createAsync(largePersonGroupId, new CreateLargePersonGroupPersonsOptionalParameter().withName("Woman"));
System.out.println("Creating Large Person Group Person called "); 
personW.subscribe(response -> System.out.print(response.name()));
```

Comment: If the call is really asynchronous, you need a way to wait for the `print` to be called. For example, sleeping in the main method. Also do not ignore the onError callback because you may be actually getting an error instead of a response.

Comment: I also looked up the method in debugging and it actually returns a Observable.OnSubscribe interface which only has one function, Call(). Would that make any difference? Also, I do have the larger method in a try/catch, is that just as good as onError()?

Comment: Which method? Also try-catch doesn't work around async sequences.

Comment: Turns out I was able to email the PM for the SDK and he recommended to use `.toBlocking().single()` and that worked very well. I guess it was an async feature, the method was not finishing in time for the print statement.

Answer (score 0):

if you're calling this code from the main() function, you will not see the logs, what I think is that this function `createAsync(..)` do work in a background thread, so to return to the main thread you have tow options.

the clean one is to use `ObserveOn()`
So the code will be like this

```
    rx.Observable<Person> personW = client.largePersonGroupPersons()
    .createAsync(largePersonGroupId, new CreateLargePersonGroupPersonsOptionalParameter().withName("Woman"))
.observeOn(mainthread())//get result in the main thread
        .subscribe(result -> {
            System.out.println("Creating Large Person Group Person called "); 
    })
```

This `mainthread()` should return a scheduler, and that's for you to figure out, in Android we get this by `observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())`

the second option is to put `blockingGet()` as you mentioned, but this will freeze the thread

Comment: Thanks Mohamed, I did hear using blocking() was not the best solution. But unless I get bad results, I'll use it for now. Thanks for this alternative though! It looks nice and short.

Comment: you're welcome @Azurespot I'll be thankful if you could accept my answer if it works for you

Comment: @Mohammed, I didn't end up using your solution, but perhaps someone else will!